# How to generate web service reference without INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, inotifypropertychanged

I am using [Fody](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/074a2a26-d034-46f1-8fe1-0da97265eb7a) in a SilverLight project to auto-generate property dependencies. However, it doesn't work if setters already contain a `RaisePropertyChanged` method call.

A workaround could be to generate web service reference code without `INotifyPropertyChanged` and instead implement it in a partial method.

How can I generate web service reference code without `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

I have a WCF service, let's call it MaterialService.svc. It looks something like this:

```cs
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMaterialService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Material GetMaterial(int id);
}

[DataContract]
public class Material
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I add the service as a Service Reference and generate client code, every class is set to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```cs
public partial class Material : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private int IDField;

    private string NameField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public int ID {
        get {
            return this.IDField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.IDField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.IDField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public System.Nullable<string> Name {
        get {
            return this.NameField;
        }
        set {
            if ((this.NameField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                this.NameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I generate client code that doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After you add the service reference, open the file `Reference.svcmap` under the service reference (you may need to enable the "show all files" option in the "Project" menu). There find the `<EnableDataBinding>` element, and change the value to false. That will remove the `INotifyPropertyChanged` from the generated data contracts.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot :) For anyone having the same issue as me re Fody, I contacted Simon Cropp and he made a new version that supports existing RaisePropertyChanged calls, so that also fixed the problem, but still this is nice to know :)